# Master method and choosing $\epsilon$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am reading [CLRS3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844), currently Chapter 4 and Section 
4.5, *"The master method for solving recurrences."*

I understood what is the $\epsilon$ , but I can't understand why they choose $ \epsilon \thickapprox 0.2$ here :

> $$T(n) = 3T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + n\lg n$$
>   we have $a=3$, $b=4$, $f(n) = n\lg n$, and $n^{\log_b a}=n^{\log_4 3}=O(n^{0.793})$. Since $f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_4 3+\epsilon})$, where $\epsilon \approx 0.2$, case 3 applies if we can show that the regularity condition holds for $f(n)$. [...] (See [picture](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/1pAMNynP.png) for a copy of the text.)

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [Case 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3) to apply, you need $f(n) = \Omega( n^{\log_b a+\epsilon} )$ for *some* constant $\epsilon>0$.

In this problem $a=3$, $b=4$ and $f(n) = n\log n$, so that you need to exhibit a value of $\epsilon>0$ such that $n\log n = \Omega(n^{\log_4 3+\epsilon})$; which amounts to saying $\underbrace{\log_4 3}_{\simeq 0.792}+\epsilon\leq 1$.

Here, they chose $\epsilon \simeq 0.2$ because this works. Absolutely *any* value of $\epsilon$ such that $$\log_4 3 < \log_4 3+\epsilon \leq 1$$ would have done the job as well.

Comment: What you said is not true... You are reading in the context of the book.

Comment: @WinVineeth  What do you mean? What did I say that is wrong — can you be specific?

Comment: The problem is that the $\epsilon$ value should be nearly 0.2 because that's how order of is defined as. nlogn is considered here. Please read the book available online to get it's context.

Comment: No. I reiterate, any value of $\epsilon$ as stated above would work... there is nothing special about the specific value $0.2$, read the statement of the theorem in the book (or point to an actual excerpt of it that says so). Furthermore, your comment on the tight "order of convergence" of $n\log n$ does not make sense: no matter the value of $\epsilon$, there is no possible choice that makes $n\log n = \Theta(n^{\log_5 4 + \epsilon})$. The only thing that matters is the $\Omega$ criterion, as stated both in the theorem and in its application; for which e.g. $\epsilon=0.001$ would also work.

Comment: @Clement C : thanks very much. I got it . do we can't choose $\epsilon$ > 0.2 because of $n^{1+x} > n log n$ where $x \in R^{+}$ ?

Comment: @bluemmb Yes (although, asymptotically, maybe not for small values of $n$). $0.00000001$, $0.1$, $0.2$, $0.201$ would work: but if you take $\epsilon > 1-\log_4 3  \simeq 0.2075$ (sorry, in a comment above I wrote $\log_5 4$ instead of $\log_43$, from my phone), then you have $\alpha = \epsilon+ \log_4 3 > 1$ and  $n\log n =o(n^{\alpha})$ (i.e., $f(n) \ll n^\alpha$ asymptotically).

Comment: @Clement C : your answers was awesome. you learn me a lot . thanks and sorry I have not enough reputation for upvote your answer but I will do it soon.

Comment: @bluemmb Glad I could help!

Comment: Hi, i'm a little late this but what is good way to determine the max value of $\epsilon$? What if I have for example $\log_4(15)$ based on a and b value of the function. $\epsilon-1$ in this case would be negative.